# Can I add a code comment that will show a Sonar warning after a Sonar scan?

Tags: sonarqube

Can I add a code comment that will show a Sonar warning after a Sonar scan?

For example, I can put '//NOSONAR' on a line to get sonar to ignore the line.

But, could I force a warning message on a line with something like this:

```
//SONAR_WARNING Show this message in Sonar
```

I just thought it would be useful as a code marker for me to mark certain lines of code with TODO items.    Or, is this just a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `// TODO` comments and enable the rule [TODO tags should be handled](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1135) on your quality profile.

Alternatively, you can create a manual issue on the given line from the SonarQube UI (if you have the "Browse" permission on the project).

Comment: According to this SO post, this feature has been removed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39118660/4573065