# How to create a manual issue in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

In my web_api page ( EX: http://'my-site-name'/web_api/api/issues ) I can’t find any api for creating an issue.I can see other apis like Assign/Unassign an issue,api/issues/add_comment,api/issues/delete_comment etc . 
While trying the following method, I have got the error message like this
curl -X POST -v -u admin:admin 'http://localhost:9000/api/issues/create?component=myproject:myfile&rule=manual:performance&line=2&severity=BLOCKER&message=blabla'

{"err_code":404,"err_msg":"No action responded to create. Actions: actions, add_comment, admin_required, authorized?, available_locales, bulk_change, changelog, current_user, current_user=, delete_comment, edit_comment, error_to_json, error_to_xml, format_datetime, handle_remember_cookie!, has_role?, is_admin?, is_user?, java_facade, json_not_supported, jsonp, kill_remember_cookie!, load_resource, logged_in?, login_from_basic_auth, login_from_cookie, login_from_session, login_required, logout_keeping_session!, logout_killing_session!, parse_datetime, redirect_back_or_default, render_access_denied, render_bad_request, render_error, render_java_exception, render_not_found, render_response, render_success, resource_required, select_authorized, send_remember_cookie!, store_location, text_not_supported, transitions, valid_remember_cookie?, and xml_not_supported"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ability to create manual issues has been removed in SonarQube 5.5 : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7472

Comment: I want to thank you for the concern. Is there any paid version or any other plugin available to do the same ??

Comment: In SonarQube, there's no way to have such feature. We're thinking that this is related to code review, and a lot of great tools (like GitHub) already exists and are doing it a better way that we would do.